# How to make a loading animation for windows8 app

Tags: javascript, animation, windows-8, loading

I've got a windows8 app that i've made via javascript,css and html and it displays a rss feed.
Sometimes this feed can take from 2-10 seconds to load, which isn't a problem from me but for people who need the app, they want to know that its loading and not frozen.
I have a animated loading animation (GIF) but i don't know how to display it while the rss feed it loading.
Any ideas? Thanks for your time.

This is the main javascript,

```
(function () {
"use strict";

  WinJS.Binding.optimizeBindingReferences = true;

  var app = WinJS.Application;
  var activation = Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;
  var articlesList;

  app.onactivated = function (args) {
    if (args.detail.kind === activation.ActivationKind.launch) {
        if (args.detail.previousExecutionState !== activation.ApplicationExecutionState.terminated) {
            // TODO: This application has been newly launched. Initialize
            // your application here.
        } else {
            // TODO: This application has been reactivated from suspension.
            // Restore application state here.
        }

        articlesList = new WinJS.Binding.List();
        var publicMembers = { ItemList: articlesList };
        WinJS.Namespace.define("C9Data", publicMembers);

        args.setPromise(WinJS.UI.processAll().then(downloadC9BlogFeed));
      }
  };

  function downloadC9BlogFeed() {
    WinJS.xhr({ url: "http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/RSS" }).then(function (rss) {  // this is where it is calling the RSS
      var items = rss.responseXML.querySelectorAll("item");

      for (var n = 0; n < items.length; n++) {
        var article = {};
        article.title = items[n].querySelector("title").textContent;
        var thumbs = items[n].querySelectorAll("thumbnail");
        if (thumbs.length > 1) {
          article.thumbnail = thumbs[1].attributes.getNamedItem("url").textContent;
          article.content = items[n].textContent;
          articlesList.push(article);
        }
      }
    });
  }

  app.oncheckpoint = function (args) {
    // TODO: This application is about to be suspended. Save any state
    // that needs to persist across suspensions here. You might use the
    // WinJS.Application.sessionState object, which is automatically
    // saved and restored across suspension. If you need to complete an
    // asynchronous operation before your application is suspended, call
    // args.setPromise().
  };

  app.start();
})();
```

Comment: How are you loading your feed? Assuming you're doing some kind of async request, you could show your GIF as you initiate the request, and hide it in the callback when the response returns.

Comment: This is the main javascript,

Answer (score 0):

@mleroy already described the correct way to load it. Pseudo code (CoffeeScript):

```
downloadC9BlogFeed = () ->
  listView.style.display = 'none'
  placeholderAnimation.style.display = 'block'
  WinJS.xhr(url)
  .then (rss) ->
    items = rss.responseXML.querySelectorAll("item")
    items.forEach (item) ->
       [process the item without having to use items[n] multiple times]
  .then () ->
    placeholderAnimation.style.display = 'none'
    listView.style.display = 'block'
```

Comment: Sorry, im really bad at javascript and coffeescript. Where it says [your processing here, would i put the script in to load the rss?

Comment: I updated the sample code a bit. The block between the first continuation ("then") and the second is basically the same code you already have, i.e. the whole "function (rss) {...}"

Comment: so if i was to paste that code straight into the javascript file it should work? Also do need to do anything with placeholderAnimation? e.g. making it a div or a css rule?... Also thanks for your help so far :)

Comment: yes, placeholderAnimation is meant to be a div with an id="placeholderAnimation" wherein you place your animation or content that you want to diplay while the feed is loading. And of course you'd need to convert my pseudo code into real JavaScript but I'm always too lazy to write all this "function() {}" and "var foo" noise in sample code.